# Change directory for uploading image

Tags: laravel, file-upload, location, storage

How can I change the directory of the uploaded images.
I want to upload it in the App/public/files folder.

My code here:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Organigramme $organigramme)
    {
    $id = $organigramme->id;
    $organigramme = Organigramme::find($id);
    $organigramme->matricule = $request->input('matricule');

    if ($request->has('profile_image'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('profile_image');
        $name = str_slug($request->input('matricule'));
        $folder = '/uploads/images/';
        $filePath = $folder . $name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $name);

        $organigramme->profile_image = $filePath;
        $organigramme->save();
    }
    return view( 'admin.organigrammes.show', compact('organigramme'));
   }
```

---

```
public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
{
    $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : str_random(25);

    $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name.'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(), $disk);

    return $file;
}
```

Comment: `$folder = '/uploads/images/';` change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config/filesystems file add a new save path.For example:

```
  'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path().'/app/public/files',
    ],
```

In the code itself, use the following code to save:

Storage::disk('images')->put($path, $image);

Comment: Thanks. You save my day